# Incomplete FLWOR expression: expecting 'return'

Tags: if-statement, xquery, basex, flwor, conditional-expressions

I am having some trouble with the if-then-else command of the XQuery.

Currently I am using BaseX to edit XQuery (if that matters!)

```
if ($item/pf3:Current/pf3:Name) then (
    let $Name := "None"
) else (
    let $Name := data($item/pf3:Current/pf3:Name)
)
```

This piece throws an error saying: 
[XPST0003] Incomplete FLWOR expression: expecting 'return'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small problem with your xquery. Here is the corrected version -

```
let $Name :=
if ($item/pf3:Current/pf3:Name) 
then "None" 
else data($item/pf3:Current/pf3:Name)
```

If there are no return statements following the above assignment statement, you can append the following return statement after the above statements -

```
return $Name
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Just one thing... if what to have something without the else part, would it be like 

let $Name :=
if ($item/pf3:Current/pf3:Name) 
then "None" 
else ()

Comment: Yes you can specify () if you don't want an else.